# Event handler can't be found in MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik

I have a silverlight application. One of StackPanel will display the table. The first column is a check box.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Complete" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Something, Converter={StaticResource ShortToBooleanConverter}}" Checked="Complete_Checked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

What I want is that once I click the box, a message box with Y/N pops up. I do have a `Complete_Checked` method in MVVM. But I get the error

> Event handler 'Complete_Checked` not found on class.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use click event handlers with MVVM you need to use `CommandBinding` or `DataBinding` depending on what you're doing.

With your example you'll use data binding. You want to bind to the checkbox dependency property called `IsChecked`. You'll also want to use the Mode of TwoWay. This will allow the UI to update the bound property when it changes.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckBoxIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Then in your object **model** not **viewmodel**

```
private bool _checkBoxIsChecked;

public bool CheckBoxIsChecked
{
   get{ return _checkBoxIsChecked;}
   set{_checkBoxIsChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxIsChecked"); }
}
```

Comment: So [this answer from telerik](http://www.telerik.com/forums/problem-to-catch-checked-change-event-from-gridviewcheckboxcolumn-type-of-column) is wrong?

Comment: @Bigeyes They aren't taking an MVVM approach. They are using the behind code of the Xaml. The give away is that they have access to the control. You see where the OP write 'radGridView1' that's a control they have access to. He or she is operating in the Xaml.CS file.

Comment: The thing is I already binding "Something", I don't have control on it. Can I bind two items?

Comment: If you're already binding to it then break point on the setter of your property. The setter gets called when the check changes. You can invoke what ever logic you want from there

Comment: So in your code `CheckBoxIsChecked` property must be living this MVVM class? I am not strong on MVVM, not sure how the xaml file and cs file assoicated eachother? From their name prefix?

Comment: In the MVVM structure, Model-View-ViewModel, the Xaml file is your View. It handles all things UI related. The Xaml.cs file, also known as the behind code, is an extension of this and should only handle UI related things. Your ViewModel handles all of your logic and processing. It does the business things. Adding, subtracting, split and combine things. Finally your Models are your data. Nothing more. They are just classes with basic properties in them. An example would be a person class. Has a name, age, gender. No logic.

Comment: Microsoft Introduction to MVVM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k77dqVVWgB8

Comment: Let me reword my question with example. Say I have AView.xaml and BView.xaml. Also I have AViewModel.cs and BViewMode.cs. How do we know AView.xaml hooks AViewModel.cs? Just from their prefix name?

Comment: You don't. That's the point of MVVM. The view and the models are reuseable. Someone we work with could create some xaml and then I could write a viewmodel for it and you could write a viewmodel for it. They might both work and be totally different

Comment: The way you would hook your viewmodel to your view is by going into your Xaml.cs constructor and saying this.DataContext = new MyViewModel()

Comment: Hi, I added it. But my goal is to pop up a message box. Do I need a method to do it besides your property?

Comment: I answered the question that you posted to the best of my ability. If you have another please create a new question and post the code for it. Otherwise you are preventing other people from easily being able to find question answer solutions on the site

Comment: Sure things. Thanks.